# How do I align the view to the local axis of an object?

Tags: 3d-view

How can I get standard axis views (<kbd>Numpad</kbd> <kbd>1</kbd>,<kbd>3</kbd>,<kbd>7</kbd>,<kbd>9</kbd>) in local axis instead of global? The motivation is simple, I was using these view for modelling my object, now I moved it, but want to edit it again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd> in combination with any of those number pad numbers to align to the local axes of the selected object.

Note that this will only work if you have rotated your object in object mode and haven't applied the rotation. If you have rotated in edit mode or applied the rotation then you can select a face (or vertices or edges) of the object and use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (<kbd>3</kbd>,<kbd>7</kbd>,<kbd>9</kbd> etc.) to align the view relative to the axis of the selected element.

If you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> in combination with the numpad numbers you will align to the *opposite* view of the object's axes, e.g. bottom, back instead of top, front.